# How to split string python that start and ends with a specific value regex?

Tags: python, regex, string, regex-group

I have the string
{id:dac62466,title:How do I refer my friends?}

I want to only get the "How do I refer my friends?"

I tried
`r'title:(\w+\s)`
but that only detect 'How'

Comment: try https://regex101.com/r/SP2RZ3/1 regex101 is a nice website to understand regex

Comment: Oh, you want to match the tail of the string beginning with the first capital letter, excluding the right brace (`'}'`) at the end. No? Maybe you want the beginning of the string to follow the second colon, or maybe to follow `"title:"`. What you haven't given us, which we need to answer your question is the *rule* that identifies the substring that is to be matched.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`\w` does not match spaces or characters like `?`. You can instead match all characters until the closing `}`.

```py
print(re.search(r'title:([^}]+)', some_string).group(1))
```

Comment: You might put a word boundary before `title` so that words such as `'subtitle'` don't match. Incidently, we have not been told that all strings of interest follow `"title:"`, only that it does in this single example.